# How to debug Rust on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, rust

I had a hard time finding any useful information about the Rust debugging story on iOS/Android. I guess I can somehow use the same mechanism that allows remote debugging for C++, but I don't know where to start.

My first attempt was to use Android Studio with the Rust plugin by JetBrains, but it seems they see this issue as [expected behavior](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/3399).

My next take will be to try bypass UI and set breakpoints via `lldb`/`gdb` directly, but I see it as a crutch.

How can I debug Rust code on Android/iOS? It will be excellent if I could do it with some UI.

Answer (score 4):

Say you've built and deployed a Rust library on Android following [these steps](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html). In order to debug via rust-gdb or graphically with CLion do the following:

- Stop gradle from stripping your Rust .so files of debug symbols by adding `packagingOptions.doNotStrip "**/*.so"` to `app/build.gradle`
- Push the gdbserver binary from Android NDK's `prebuild` directory to the device:

```
~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/android-x86_64/gdbserver$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb push gdbserver /data/local/tmp
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell "chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/gdbserver"
```

- Restart adbd as root:

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb root
```

- Forward a port that you will use for gdbserver:

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:1337 tcp:1337
```

- Attach gdbserver to the process you wish to debug:

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell
generic_x86_64:/ # su
generic_x86_64:/ # set enforce 0
generic_x86_64:/ # /data/local/tmp/gdbserver :1337 --attach $(ps -A | grep your.android.application.id | awk '{print $2}')
```

- Either run `rust-gdb` or set up CLion's "Remote GDB" configuration with:

```
target remote tcp:localhost:1337
```